# web counters in files?

Tags: php, hitcounter

How do I store counters in php script without DB? Always was using DB but now I want simpler configuration... Using files seems to be problematic due to file locks. Let's say that there are many concurrent connections and I want to count number of script executions.

Comment: ok, it seems that the solution is to work with files for small loads and work with db on high loads

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use a database and you don't want to use a file. I don't think it's possible to achieve that without using either of those.

Comment: I suppose if you were *very* eccentric, you could utilise HTML5 local storage to store the number on all clients' machines, and also store it in memcache. Every time that script is run, the localStorage value is checked (by making an AJAX call, of course), which will hopefully be smaller than the cached value. If the cached value is smaller, then the cache value is replaced by the value stored in local storage. No databases or files (on the server) used. How's that for thinking outside the box? ;)

Comment: @JulianH.Lam Good Idea. But, that's an over-kill for such a simple task.

Comment: overkill indeed. and if i'd have memcache i could mysql as well

Comment: Oh definitely overkill... was just disproving your "don't think it's possible" in your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can increment a cached value in memory using something like memcache. It's probably the fastest solution to the concurrency problem.

[Memcache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.examples-overview.php)  or [APC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-add.php)

Ofcourse you'll lose the data if memcache is cleared or restarted... file-persistence at some point is the only way.

Comment: i'd like to have simplest deployment solution possible, so that it would work even on shared hosting. so basically it looks like mysql or files, as even sqlite is platform-dependent

Comment: @EugeneShaineMednikov Maybe you should have included those specs in your original question? That's pretty limiting.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$count_file = "counts.txt";
$counts = file($count_file);
$counts[0] ++;
$fp = fopen($count_file , "w");
fputs($fp , "$counts[0]");
fclose($fp);
echo $counts[0];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to count number of script executions

Setup a directory you can write to. For each request create a new file with a random name.

You count the number of script executions by counting the number of files.

If you do the random with a low collision rate, you won't loose a count, or only very, very few. If you know the characteristics of the random source and hash function for the file-name, you can even statistically say how many counts you need to add.

Comment: Ok, it's not **so** trivial, I need to store stats, not just number of files, e.g. there will be several counters. Ok, let's say I can use folder for each counter, per day. But 100k files per day will hurt much more than file lock ).

Comment: Each 10 minutes run a job via cron that get's the listing of the created files, counts them, deletes them and raise that count inside another file. As it runs every ten minutes only, it won't run into file-locking problems. You have solved your problem. Encapsulate the overall method into a class so you can replace that later on with database etc.

Comment: and if I don't have cron? ok, let's say i'll need to solve cron problem anyway. I think this solution will be worse on reads, as at the same time I need to increment counter I'll need to also read several counters and I believe that counting number of files in folders is slower that reading line from small file.

Comment: The solution to your question is called database anyway. My answer is only a suggestion if you want to count file-based, how you can prevent to run into file-locking. That's all. You need to decide for a solution anyway, and each one has it's downsides too: Database: You don't want. Counter-File: Stalls on locking. My suggestion: More work.